# Setting range on a frequency vs POSIXct date bar chart breaks with R plotly when there is only 1 bar to plot

Tags: r, plotly, posixct, r-plotly

I am plotting the number of datafiles measured by an instrument as frequency per day in barchart form with plotly.

*This plot is used inside a shiny app and the date range, number of files per day and so on all depend on what selections the user makes in terms of data, so I need to have it work for both scenarios described below*

Two plots, 1 identical block of code to make it, the only difference is the number of bars is 1 or >1. 1 bar plot is broken, >1 bar plot works fine and it makes no sense to me at all!

The plot works great when plotting 2 or more days with or without setting a range

`range = c(dateRangeMin,dateRangeMax)` inside `layout()` is setting the range and seems to break the plot in a **1 bar scenario**.

The dates are in `POSIXct` format, `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`, and the i'm setting is also in this format

The plot also works when there is only data present on 1 day, when I do not set the range. As soon as I set the range to be wider than just 8 milliseconds (automatic scale), the plot is scaled properly, but the bar for that one day disappears, and it makes no sense at all.

**SCENARIO 1: BROKEN**

```
library(plotly)
#make a dataframe with 1 full date
dayPOSIXct <- as.POSIXct("2016-05-20 19:03:36",format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
# 1 frequency value (nr of samples
frequency <- 1
# reduce full date to 1 day for counting samples per day
day <- format(as.POSIXct(dayPOSIXct, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), format = '%Y-%m-%d')
# give a tag for coloring (files can be in or out of selected date range
datecoloring <- "IN"
# put it together in a dataframe
MyDF_dayfreq <- data.frame(day = day, frequency = frequency, dayPOSIXct = dayPOSIXct, datecoloring = datecoloring)

# calculate the min and max dates of the dataframe for setting range in the plot
# I add 14 hours to the max, and subtract 14 hours from the min to widen the range of the plot  
dateRangeMin <- as.POSIXct( min(MyDF_dayfreq$dayPOSIXct), format = '%Y-%m-%d')-14*3600
dateRangeMax <- as.POSIXct( max(MyDF_dayfreq$dayPOSIXct), format = '%Y-%m-%d')+14*3600

p <-  plot_ly(data = MyDF_dayfreq, source = 'DateRangeHisto',  x = ~dayPOSIXct, y =  ~frequency,   type = "bar",
              color  = as.factor(MyDF_dayfreq$datecoloring), colors = c('#339fff', '#eaf5ff'),
              opacity= 0.5, showlegend = T,
              marker = list(line = list(width = 2, color = '#0000ff')),
              hoverinfo = "text",
              text = ~paste('Files:', MyDF_dayfreq$frequency, '<br>Date:', format(MyDF_dayfreq$day, format = '%Y-%m-%d'), sep = ' '))%>%

  layout(xaxis = list(title = "Date", showgrid = F, showline = T, range = c(dateRangeMin,dateRangeMax), list(tickformat = 'yyyy-mm-dd')),
         yaxis = list(title = "File count", showgrid = F, showline = T, range =c(0,2), tickformat=',d' ),
         margin = list(
           r = 10,
           t = 10,
           b = 40,
           l = 20
         ))
```

[image: 1 bar plot]

**SCENARIO 2: WORKING**

```
dayPOSIXct <- as.POSIXct(c("2016-05-20 19:03:36", "2016-05-21 19:03:36"), format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
frequency <- c(1,1)
day <- format(as.POSIXct(dayPOSIXct, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), format = '%Y-%m-%d')
MyDF_dayfreq <- data.frame(day = day, frequency = frequency, dayPOSIXct = dayPOSIXct, datecoloring = datecoloring)
dateRangeMin <- as.POSIXct( min(MyDF_dayfreq$dayPOSIXct), format = '%Y-%m-%d')-14*3600
dateRangeMax <- as.POSIXct( max(MyDF_dayfreq$dayPOSIXct), format = '%Y-%m-%d')+14*3600

p <-  plot_ly(data = MyDF_dayfreq, source = 'DateRangeHisto',  x = ~dayPOSIXct, y =  ~frequency,   type = "bar",
              color  = as.factor(MyDF_dayfreq$datecoloring), colors = c('#339fff', '#eaf5ff'),
              opacity= 0.5, showlegend = T,
              marker = list(line = list(width = 2, color = '#0000ff')),
              hoverinfo = "text",
              text = ~paste('Files:', MyDF_dayfreq$frequency, '<br>Date:', format(MyDF_dayfreq$day, format = '%Y-%m-%d'), sep = ' '))%>%

  layout(xaxis = list(title = "Date", showgrid = F, showline = T, range = c(dateRangeMin,dateRangeMax), list(tickformat = 'yyyy-mm-dd')),
         yaxis = list(title = "File count", showgrid = F, showline = T, range =c(0,2), tickformat=',d' ),
         margin = list(
           r = 10,
           t = 10,
           b = 40,
           l = 20
         ))
p
```

[image: 2 bar plot]

Inside my app the plot would look like this, and it all works, except for the 1 bar situation...
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I got you right. You need to play with bar width. For number of bars = 1 ther is bar but very thiny you need to zoom in to see it. But you can set fix width or scale properly with parameter:

```
        dateRangeMin <- as.POSIXct( min(MyDF_dayfreq$dayPOSIXct), format = '%Y-%m-%d')-1*36
    dateRangeMax <- as.POSIXct( max(MyDF_dayfreq$dayPOSIXct), format = '%Y-%m-%d')+1*36

    p <-  plot_ly(data = MyDF_dayfreq, source = 'DateRangeHisto', 
                  color  = as.factor(MyDF_dayfreq$datecoloring), colors = c('#339fff', '#eaf5ff'),
                  opacity= 0.5, showlegend = T,
                  marker = list(line = list(width = 2, color = '#0000ff')),
                  hoverinfo = "text",
                  text = ~paste('Files:', MyDF_dayfreq$frequency, '<br>Date:', format(MyDF_dayfreq$day, format = '%Y-%m-%d'), sep = ' '))%>%


####################################    update
    add_bars( x = ~dayPOSIXct, y =  ~frequency,   type = "bar", width=20000 
              )%>%
 ##################################     
      layout(xaxis = list(title = "Date"#, showgrid = F# , showline = T
                          , range = c(dateRangeMin,dateRangeMax)#, list(tickformat = 'yyyy-mm-dd')
                          ),
             yaxis = list(title = "File count"#, showgrid = F, showline = T#, range =c(0,2), tickformat=',d' 
                          )
             #,
             #margin = list(r = 10,t = 10,b = 40,l = 20)
             )
```

Comment: ah yes that solves it to some extend. I do notice that my bar then isn't centered above 12:00 anymore then though

Comment: Ah wait, in my demo they weren't centered on 12:00 anyway. Ok, I will play a bit with it and see if I solved all problems now. bar width 50000000 it is I guess haha